# Noise cancelling headset picking up laptop noise during recordings

Tags: headphones

I am using a normal headset + mic for recording my screencasts, but it always picks up the noise of my laptop processor or fan.

Is there any way to kill that noise, or do I have to switch my headset to a better one?

Comment: Are you willing to spend some money? Noise cancellation will not work perfectly at all times. The best solution will always be to get a better microphone that's closer to your mouth and reduce the background noise (is your laptop really *that* loud?).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a second mic to pick up the background noise and audio processing software to subtract the two signals, but the positioning of the second mic would have to be fairly precise to pick up the noise but not the voice.

Answer (score 1):

What mic are you using ?

I once had a directional microphone (bundled with an Asus motherboard), which only picked up my voice and hardly any other noise.

There's another almost free option : Zalman ZM-MIC1. It is truly **amazing** considering its ultra low price ($5), and most interesting : it's a clip-on microphone : closer to your mouth, further from the noise ;)

[image]